# Python delete a node in linked list, given just access to that node

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

This is a LeetCode question, I knew its solution, but wondering about why my code not work.

> Write a function to delete a node (except the tail) in a singly linked list, given only access to that node.
>
> Supposed the linked list is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 and you are given the third node with value 3, the linked list should become 1 -> 2 -> 4 after calling your function

At first glance, my intution is delete like an array:

shift all the node values one front, then delete the tail, here's my implementation and test case:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
        
node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(2)
node3 = ListNode(3)
node4 = ListNode(4)
node5 = ListNode(5)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = node4
node4.next = node5


    
def deleteNode(node):
    """
    :type node: ListNode
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify node in-place instead.
    """
    while node.next:
        node.val = node.next.val
        node = node.next
    node = None
    
    
deleteNode(node4)
```

But After deletion, it has two 5 value nodes, the tail was still kept, can anyone please explain to me what's wrong here?

```
deleteNode(node4)

node1.val
Out[162]: 1

node1.next.val
Out[163]: 2

node1.next.next.val
Out[164]: 3

node1.next.next.next.val
Out[165]: 5

node1.next.next.next.next.val
Out[166]: 5
```

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were almost there, but are doing way too much work shifting *all* `val` values up one node. You also failed to clear the last `next` reference, which is why you see `5` printed *twice*. I'll show you how to solve the problem properly first, then address removing the tail.

You can indeed solve this puzzle by *not* deleting the node, just by setting the `value` to the next value, and the `next` pointer to the node after the next. And that is **all** you need to do, you don't need to touch any of the following nodes. You'd effectively delete the next node and making *this* node hold the next value instead:

```
      node
       |
       v
      ---------        ---------       
---> | val: va | ---> | val: vb | ---> ?
      ---------        ---------
```

becomes

```
      node
       |
       v
      ---------        ---------       
---> | val: vb | -+   | val: vb |   -> ?
      ---------   |    ---------   |   
                  |                |
                   ----------------
```

So the implementation is as simple as:

```
def deleteNode(node):
    """
    :type node: ListNode
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify node in-place instead.
    """
    node.val = node.next.val
    node.next = node.next.next
```

No loop required.

Back to your attempt, note that the last line in your function has no effect. `node` is a *local name* in your function, and references the tail `ListNode` instance, *until* you set it to `None` instead.

You had this:

```
      node
       |
       v
      -----------       
---> | val: tail | ---> None 
      -----------
```

and `node = None` does this:

```
      node -> None
       X
       |
       v
      -----------       
---> | val: tail | ---> None 
      -----------
```

That incoming reference from the previous node is *still there*.

You'd have to track the 'one-but-last' node reference and clear the `.next` attribute on that once looping is done:

```
while node.next:
    node.val = node.next.val
    prev, node = node, node.next

# clear reference to tail
prev.next = None
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I did a more work than needed, and could you look at my code, I think I did clean the tail, but the tail still there confused me.

Comment: @o-o: `node = None` only sets the local name. The reference in the preceding node is unaffected.

Comment: You make it so simple. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def deleteNode(node):
   node.val = node.next.val
   node.next = node.next.next
```

Since you don't have a reference to your current node, you can't delete it.
But you do have a ref to your next node.
So give your current node the role that your next node previously had,
and then the garbage collector will delete your next node, since there are no refs to it left because you overwrote node.next.